# Deb installer: how to set Source, License, Icon

Tags: deb

I created deb installer for my program. It has control file. But I don't know to to fill:

- Source: Ubuntu 16.04 shows this field empty
- License: the same
- Icon: Ubuntu shows only blue template of icon

Preview of Ubuntu with installer is:
[Deb preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lpzd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For license, you should use another file: **copyright**.

Here an example:

```
Format: https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/

Files: *
Copyright: 1975-2010 Ulla Upstream
License: GPL-2+

Files: debian/*
Copyright: 2010 Daniela Debianizer
License: GPL-2+

Files: debian/patches/fancy-feature
Copyright: 2010 Daniela Debianizer
License: GPL-3+

Files: */*.1
Copyright: 2010 Manuela Manpager
License: GPL-2+
```